# CSS wont load on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Im in the process of developing a site.  It's coming along well save the fact that none of the css works on IE8. Ive been reading around online and have had some trouble making sense of the various guides and hacks that offer a solution.  Any suggestion on how to make this start working? heres a snippet of code to help.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/272026200.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Dupont Studios</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="waypoints.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)" href="style.css" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        // Do our DOM lookups beforehand
        var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
        var nav = $("nav");
        nav_container.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
        nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');

        }
        });
        $("li.nav-item").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
        });

        });

    </script>



</head>
```

More info:
the ie8.css sheet is simply a copy of the style.css that I made as a test. I saw somewhere online that ending something in \9 could help.  Here's a snippet of the code.  In retrospect this seems quite dumb

```
body{
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica Neue Light', sans-serif\9;
    margin:0\9;

}

#top-container{
    width:100%\9;
    height:100%\9;
}

#top-content{
    max-width:1200px\9;
    margin-right:auto\9;
    margin-left:auto\9;
}

#top-img{
    width:100%\9;
    padding-bottom: 10%\9;
}
```

Comment: Which stylesheet(s) do not load properly? Is it the `ie8.css` one or all of them?

Comment: Did you watch your web traffic using Fiddler or another tool to verify that IE8.css is downloading successfully? If you hit F12, does it show that your page is in IE8 Standards Mode?

Comment: when i first discovered the problem, it was style.css that wasnt loading properly, there was simply no css. I tried making a separate css file called ie8.css which also simply doesnt load.

is there a tool besides fiddler i can use to see if its loading?

Comment: I'm curious, what does the inline style in the head tag `<head style="overflow-x: hidden">` do?

Comment: @hungerstar, if contents on the x axis stick out, theyre simply hidden now

Comment: @nictoriousface but the `<head>` tag is not a visual element.  Why would you worry about it's contents sticking out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 8 and below only responds to `screen` and `print` in the `media` property.

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="mobile.css" />
```

And add the media queries in your CSS file(s):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body { 
    ...
  }
  ..
}
```

Respond.js, as others have noted, should help with compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 (or, specifically, any IE version before IE9) does not fully support CSS3 media queries, which is why your mobile.css and style.css stylesheets are not loading.

Here are [some suggestions (such as using a JS library like Respond.js) for how to keep IE8 users happy](http://danielsworkshop.com/blog/2013/01/05/how-to-get-ie8-to-understand-css-media-queries/).

Comment: Pin question : is there any non-pc plateform running win-xp/ie8 ? Why worry about ie<9 on responsive design if there is no way your page will be displayed on IE8 on a tablet or handheld or phone ?

Comment: @MilchePatern, I believe there are, but very few.  I'm not prepared to look it up right now, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have CSS3 media-queries running on IE8, you should use [respondjs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond):

> A fast & lightweight polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries (for IE 6-8, and more)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion - I would load in my default stylesheet first, and then declare the conditional IE stylesheet after. The idea is to use that conditional stylesheet to overwrite some things in your default stylesheet, so you won't have to put !important declarations everywhere. Hence the 'cascade'

Answer (score -1):

If it's just the ie8 stylesheet that's not loading, be aware that if IE is running in compatibility view, it will identify itself as IE7.  Thus your conditional comment would not apply and the ie8.css stylesheet would never be included.